# "Your postal code is incomplete" on Spark signup page

Tags: civicrm-spark, postcode

I'm trying to sign up for Spark, using the link found here: https://civicrm.org/spark
I've entered all my information and keep getting an error that says "Your postal code is incomplete".  There are two places to put in your zip code on this form, I have filled them both in.  I have tried the zip format and the zip+4 format.  Getting the error each time.  I get the error whether I let my browser do the autofill settings or not.  Ready and willing subscriber here, being kept from becoming your customer by this frustrating problem.  Not a great start, this does not exactly inspire confidence that I want to use this (will my subscribers have the same problem?).

Comment: You should contact spark@civicrm.org for Spark support - as far as I know at least :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just double-checking: when filling in the form, after typing the credit card number, do you see the postcode/zip field?

[image: payment form]

The payment processor (Stripe) displays a different field depending on the country (numeric ZIP for the US, alphanumeric for Canada, etc). I have to admit it's a bit confusing. I will double-check if we can do something about it.

If the issue persists, please do not hesitate to reach out by email at spark@civicrm.org.

Comment: It's really confusing for my users that the zip code doesn't come up until after they have entered other information ...  the only urgent emails I'm getting from folks is about this. ... at least could we change the default error message to say where the zip code needs to go?

Comment: Yes. This is a problem. I just outfitted a site with Stripe Payment and we're being inundated with calls about people not being able to renew their memberships. Can't Stripe collect the postal from the Postal Code field that the person has filled out our demand it when it collects the CVC?